# Apache POI: Transfer time from cell to cell

Tags: apache-poi

**Need in short**: I'd like to copy a time value from one cell to another cell.

**Problem in short**: POI 5.2.2 (or more specific: `DateUtil.internalGetExcelDate`) transforms the 08:00 o'clock from the input cell to the numeric value -1.00.

**More details**: There's an xlsx file (created with LibreOffice 7.0.4.2) with the time '08:00:00' in it:

[image: xlsx cell with 08:00:00 o'clock]

I can read that value with `sourceCell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue()`, which is fine.

But when I try to transfer that value into another cell (`targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue())`), in the `targetCell` there is the value -1 instead of the expected 08:00:00 o'clock.

Here's a screenshot while debugging the `setCellValue` call:
[image: Debugging CellBase.setCellValue]

And here's a screenshot while debugging the `DateUtil.internalGetExcelDate` call:
[image: Debugging DateUtil.internalGetExcelDate]

**Possible workaround**: I guess that it would work to evaluate the `LocalDateTime` from the `sourceCell` and if its year is < 1904 then I add some years to that the resulting `LocalDateTime` is not transformed to -1.00 by `DateUtil.internalGetExcelDate`.

This is something I don't want to do because that would set another value in the `targetCell` than there was in the `sourceCell`.

**Another workaround**: Another workaround would be to use `LocalDateTime.now()`, set the hour and minute, call `targetCell.setCellValue(...)` and then change the format like this:

```
    short format = workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("HH:MM:SS");
    CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(format);
    targetCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Unfortunately I don't know whether the `sourceCell` just contains a time or whether it contains a full timestamp. I just want to copy cell contents (which works fine with String, Number, ...).

**Actual workaround**: As a current (working) workaround I check the year and if it's <1900 then I set another year at the date, set the modified `LocalDateTime` into the cell and set the dataformat (see workaround description above).

**Question**: How can I transfer a `LocalTime` value from one cell to another cell (without manipulating the year)? I guess that my (working) workaround should not be the answer ...

Comment: 08:00 is not a DateTime - it is a time - so DateTime code is not appropriate - try just getNumericCellValue instead. - dates, dateTimes and times are just stored as numbers anyway (number of seconds since start of 1900 - usually) - it's the cell style that indicates the format of the number (including if it is a time, etc)

Comment: At a first glance it seems that `targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getNumericCellValue());` works for date, time and datetime. I had in mind that there is some special magic about date values for a 1904 leap year bug that is specially handled in `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell#getLocalDateTimeCellValue`. And it could be that there is a date or a time or a datetime in the `sourceCell`. This is why I used `getLocalDateTimeCellValue` in all three cases.

Comment: Apply the same cell style to the new cell that applied to the one you're copying the value from?

Comment: Yes, great idea. That would handle other cases (percentages, currencies, ...) too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Excel cell date types**

Microsoft Excel only has following cell data types:

- String (alphanumeric)
- Numeric (floating point number)
- Boolean (true or false)
- Formula (formula strings)
- Error (internally error codes)
- Empty (empty cell)

There is no special date cell data type as well as no special Integer cell date type.

**How Excel stores date or time or date-time**

If Excel stores date-time, it stores it as floating point number. There 1.00 is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. (There is a special case when Excel has set 1904-Date. But that is a special case only about the meaning of 1.00.).

Adding 1.00 means adding one day. Adding 1/24 means adding one hour. Adding 1/24/60 means adding one minute. Adding 1/24/60/60 means adding one second. Adding 1/24/60/60/10 means adding a tenth second and so on.

For cell values lower than 1.00, Excel interprets that as time in day 0 of month 1 in year 1900 (or 1904 if Excel has set 1904-Date). There 1/24 means one hour. 1/24 + 1/24/60 means one hour and one minute and so on. So your 08:00:00 is the cell value 8*1/24 (8 hours) = 1/3.

When reading Excel cell values the only way to determine whether Excel interprets a cell value as a date or time or date-time is to get the cell's number format too. If that is a date or time or date-time format, then Excel interprets a cell value of 1.00 as  1900-01-01, a cell value of 1/24 as 01:00:00, a cell value of 1/24 + 1/24/60 as 01:01:00 and so on.

But your observation is correct. If Apache POI reads a date-time from an Excel cell which has set only a time, which is a numeric (`double`) value between 0.00 and 1.00, then it reads a date-time of day 1899-12-31. But that is not what Excel does. For Excel the time-only value is in day 0 of month 1 in year 1900. If then Apache POI sets a date-time value of, for example 1899-12-31 08:00:00, then it sets -1 because Excel cannot have date-time values before 1900.

So the only way to set time values in Excel cells is to set numeric (`double`) values between 0.00 and 1.00 and set a cell style having a number format of `HH:MM:SS`. One cannot set a time only Excel cell value from a Java date-time value, because there is not a Java date-time value which can have  day 0 of month 1 in year 1900.

So if [DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-) tells that the source cell is date formatted and the numeric (`double`) cell value of that cell is lower than 1, then set that numeric (`double`) cell value to the new cell and format that cell the same as the source cell.

Complete example to test:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class ExcelSetCellValue {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelWithTime.xlsx")); String filePath = "./ExcelWithTimeNew.xlsx";
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelWithTime.xls")); String filePath = "./ExcelWithTimeNew.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  
  Cell sourceCell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0); // get cell value from A1: 08:00:00
  Row targetRow = sheet.getRow(5); if (targetRow==null) targetRow = sheet.createRow(5);
  Cell targetCell = targetRow.getCell(5); if (targetCell==null) targetCell = targetRow.createCell(5);
 
  if (sourceCell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC && DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(sourceCell)) {
   System.out.println(sourceCell.getNumericCellValue()); // 8*1/24 = 1/3
   System.out.println(sourceCell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue()); // 1899-12-31T08:00
   //targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue()); // does not work because sourceCell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue() is in year 1899
   targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getNumericCellValue()); 
   targetCell.setCellStyle(sourceCell.getCellStyle());
  }
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```